# Why isn't this eval working?

Tags: javascript, eval

The following dynamically generated javascript is returning `undefined` when I try to run it using `eval()`.  If I remove the `if/else` statements, it returns `0` but when I try to use the `if/else` statements, it's returning `undefined`.

```
function doCalculation() {
    var OfferSupport=0;
    var DOOfferSupport=4;
    var SupportFull=SupportFull;
    var SupportNone=SupportNone;
    if(DOOfferSupport >= 1)
        OfferSupport = SupportFull ;
    else
        OfferSupport = SupportNone ;
    return OfferSupport;
}
console.log('test: ' +  doCalculation());
```

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Please format correctly

Comment: `var SupportFull=SupportFull`? What?

Comment: that's how the eval statement is being processed, as one single line.  I'm not sending it readable javascript

Comment: Please show us how you are using `eval` to run it.  A simple function call should be enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're setting your variable to `SupportFull` or `SupportNone`, which are both undefined.

If you want to get a value back, you need to set a value.

Comment: god that was so obvious

Answer (score 2):

See your code :

```
var OfferSupport=0; 
var DOOfferSupport=4;
var SupportFull=SupportFull; 
var SupportNone=SupportNone;
if(DOOfferSupport >= 1) 
  OfferSupport = SupportFull ; 
else 
  OfferSupport = SupportNone ;
```

But you have just declared `SupportFull` and `SupportNone` , didn't assign any value to it.

Look at the [ECMAScript specs](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.9)

> **undefined value**
>
> primitive value used when a variable has not been assigned a value